# Create a analog clock widget showing time according to different time zones

Tags: android

Actually I have to make a analog clock widget showing world's time after selecting the particular time zone. I have created a analog clock with
    option of selecting the time zones.I want that the same clock with updated time zone should be displayed as a widget.I am not getting how to bring only the clock view as a widget.

My code is:

```
package nEx.Software.Tutorials.Widgets.AnalogClock;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
//import nEx.Software.Tutorials.Widgets.AnalogClock.main.CustomClock;
//import nEx.Software.Tutorials.Widgets.AnalogClock.main.MyTime;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Info extends Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener
{

     Context context;
        TextView tv;
        RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3;
        RadioGroup r1;
        FrameLayout fl1;
        LinearLayout l1;
        Timer timer;
        Date result;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp1;
        Drawable bck;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.main);

        context = this;
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        r1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup01);
        rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton01);
        rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton02);
        rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton03);
        fl1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout01);
        bck = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clockface);
         fl1.setBackgroundDrawable(bck);
        lp1 = fl1.getLayoutParams();
        r1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        result = null;
    }
    private void updateTime(String str) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
        timer = new Timer();        //digital clock
        MyTime mt = new MyTime(this, str);
        timer.schedule(mt, 1, 1000);
    }
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (rb1.isChecked() == true) {
            updateTime("GMT");

        }
        if (rb2.isChecked() == true) {
            updateTime("EST");
        }
        if (rb3.isChecked() == true) {
            updateTime("MST");
        }
    }
    public class MyTime extends TimerTask {
        String tz;
        public MyTime(Context context, String str) {
            tz = str;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Date date = new Date();
                date = getDateInTimeZone(date, tz);
                //System.out.println(date.toLocaleString());
                result = date;
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        private Date getDateInTimeZone(Date currentDate, String timeZoneId) {
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId);
            Calendar mbCal = new GregorianCalendar(tz);
            mbCal.setTimeInMillis(currentDate.getTime());
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, mbCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mbCal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mbCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mbCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mbCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, mbCal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, mbCal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
            return cal.getTime();
        }
    }
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            tv.setText(result.toLocaleString());
            //System.out.println(result.getHours()+" "+result.getMinutes());
            fl1.removeAllViews();
            fl1.addView(new CustomClock(context, lp1.height / 2, lp1.width / 2, result));
        }
    };
    public class CustomClock extends View {
        private final float x;
        private final float y;
        private final int r = 70;
        private final Date date;
        private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        public CustomClock(Context context, float x, float y, Date date) {
            super(context);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.date = date;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            //canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
            float sec = (float) date.getSeconds();
            float min = (float) date.getMinutes();
            float hour = (float) date.getHours() + min / 60.0f;
            mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
            canvas.drawLine(x, y, (float) (x + (r - 15) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((hour / 12.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))), (float) (y + (r - 10) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((hour / 12.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))), mPaint);
            canvas.save();
            mPaint.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
            canvas.drawLine(x, y, (float) (x + r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((min / 60.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))), (float) (y + r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((min / 60.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))), mPaint);
            canvas.save();
            mPaint.setColor(0xFFA2BC13);
            canvas.drawLine(x, y, (float) (x + (r + 10) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((sec / 60.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))), (float) (y + (r + 15) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((sec / 60.0f * 360.0f) - 90f))), mPaint);
        }
    }
//}
  //  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app widgets are quite limited to a few views called "remote views" . even they are not so flexible .
the reason behind this decision is probably security . you would have to get a workaround for this problem , since you cannot create your own customized view as an appwidget .
here's a list of all of the available remote views:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

you can use their analog clock if you wish.